# cannot sending email to several mail address

Tags: domain-name-system

i have domain jatek.com
i have two connection to different ISP and have public IP in each ISP
router failover fature is off.

jatek.com. is pointed to ip 1.1.1.1 so is www.jatek.com (ISP A)

mx is pointed to 2.2.2.2 (ISP B)

everything works fine, until when i send an email to @cigna.com, the mail is bouncing with error message :

**There was a SMTP communication problem with the recipient's email server.  Please contact your system administrator.**

can anyone help me please..
thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly cigna.com is not under your control. So this means the smtp server of cigna.com is malconfigured or not reachable. There is nothing you can do, as it is out of your reach.

Comment: to further complicate things. if re-route this email to our a smarthost (relay server of our isp) it gets delivered. And if i send email to cigna.com from a different domain it works? Our IP is not listed in any blacklist database either.